# Adding parsed text into String

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I was working on my first project which includes a website parser. I attempted to learn a little bit about parsers and stumbled across a library called "Jsoup" found here: 
http://jsoup.org/download

I then tried this code example which i found on a tutorial website:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HTMLParserExample1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Document doc;
    try {

        // need http protocol
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();

        // get page title
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println("title : " + title);

        // get all links
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {

            // get the value from href attribute
            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
            System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

The code worked well so i decided to attempt to combine it with the rest of my application (Which is a JFrame with a textbox inside it)

So what i attempted to do is putting what was put inside [code]System.out.println();[/code] inside a string. 
While doing this i was getting errors while i was trying to do it the following way:

```
s + "\nlink : " + link.attr("href");
s + "text : " + link.text();
```

I was getting errors and soon realised this wasnt the correct way of doing it, So i found the method String.concat and decided to use it.
After using this it still didnt work and i then also realised that what should be parsed also stopped being printed out with the System.out command..

Here is my current code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class JParser {

    private String finishedParse;

     public static void JParser() {

         //String that should hold the finished parse
         String finishedParse = new String();

         //test string used to see if what the Netbeans IDE recomended me to do work
         String tester = new String();
         finishedParse = "";

    Document doc;
    try {

        //Need http protocol
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();

        //Get page title
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println("title : " + title);

        //Get all links
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {

            //Get the value from href attribute
            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
            System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
                        tester = finishedParse.concat("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
                        tester = finishedParse.concat("text : " + link.text());
                        tester = finishedParse.concat("\n");

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

     //The method i wish to call from my other class to get the parsed text returned.
     public String getParsedText(String parsedText){
         parsedText = finishedParse;
         return parsedText;
     }
}
```

The problem now is that what is supposed to get printed with the System.out command is not being printed out and i still havn't figured out how to get the parsed text into my String.

Im realy intrested in learning and i have a hard time finding what in my code is wrong. I did search the web for answears but had no sucess.

**THE ERROR REMAINING IS THE FOLLOWING**
The two System.out statements are not printing out anything to the console, It did work when i copied the code from the tutorial. Both of the codes is in the post above, Read and help me please.

The problem was that i called the class in a strange way, My best guess is that i was tired yesterday so my ignorance kicked in..

Comment: 1) You mention errors but you don't tell us what they are.  2) Just use the + operator for string concatenation.

Comment: Im going to edit the post and include the exact problems more noticable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (Element link : links) {

  // Get the value from href attribute
  System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
  System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
  finishedParse = finishedParse.concat("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
  finishedParse = finishedParse.concat("text : " + link.text());
  finishedParse = finishedParse.concat("\n");

}
```

Notice that using `concat()` is exactly the same as using the `+` operator, the real problem was that you should update the string that's being used to concatenate the final answer. Even better, you should use a `StringBuilder` for this kind of job - it will be update in-place (whereas `concat()` returns a new string every time), so it's much more efficient.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (Element link : links) {

  // Get the value from href attribute
  System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
  System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
  sb.append("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
  sb.append("text : " + link.text());
  sb.append("\n");

}

String finishedParse = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks but i still have the problem that the two lines above adding to the finishedParse variable is not being printed out in the console..

Comment: Again thank you for taking your time and even improoving your answear but it is still only 50% of the question since what should be printed out to the console is not being printed out the two statements System.out.. is not working.

Comment: That can only be because `doc.select("a[href]");` is returning nothing, but sadly I'm not familiar enough with `Jsoup` to know why

Comment: Its strange cause when i copied the tutorial code it worked perfectly.. Thats why im soo confused.